# Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $F ⊆ X$ . Show that $F ^- = \{x ∈ X : d(x, F) = 0\}.$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $F ⊆ X$ . Show that $F 
^-  = \{x ∈ X : d(x, F) = 0\}.$

I am confused firstly with the meaning of the question. In this space where distances are all defined, is it stating that the distances for every point in $X$ with relation to a particular subspace $F$ are $0$ (Does it matter if the space is open or closed)?  Need help with the proof!

Comment: He is just asking to prove that a point $x \in X$ is in the closure of a subspace $F \subseteq X$ if and only if  $d(x,F)=\inf_{y \in F } d(x,y)$ is zero.

Comment: @AntonioAlfieri $\inf$, not $\min$

Comment: Yes you are right, I edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x\in\overline{F}$, there exists $(x_n)\in F^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that $d(x,x_n)\rightarrow 0$. For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $d(x,F)\leqslant d(x,x_n)$. Finally, one has $d(x,F)=0$.

Let $x\in X$ such that $d(x,F)=0$, using the definition of the infimum: $$\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists x_{\varepsilon}\in F\textrm{ s.t. }d(x,x_{\varepsilon})<\varepsilon.$$
Hence the result taking $\varepsilon=1/n$.

*Reminder.* For all $x\in X$, $d(x,F)=\inf\limits_{y\in F}d(x,y)$.

Comment: In the comments @Antonio posed it as an if and only if question. How come you did not approach it the same way?

Comment: If you read carefully my answer, you will see that Antonio and I are saying the exact same thing. I proved that if $x\in\overline{F}$, then $d(x,F)=0$ and conversely, if $d(x,F)=0$, then $x\in\overline{F}$.